# Transforming a image to a shape defined by image corners in earth coordinates - Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, rasterio

I have a source satellite image. It is a rectangular shape x by y. I also have the stored lon/lat coordinates of the corners and the center point in the xml meta file. Is there a way with the `gdal` or `rasterio` library in Python, to transform (scale, rotate, affine transform) the image to the shape defined in lon/lat coordinates of the corner points?

Comment: I know qgis does this when opening the tif file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you want to create a [World file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) from the coordinates of the 4 corners  and the width and height of the image

1. You get the width and height of the image with [osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/), [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) or any other libraries to open image files as [Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6444612) and others.

   ```
   dataset = rasterio.open('satel.tif')
   rasterx = dataset.width
   rastery = dataset.height
   ```
2. you need to extract the x and y values of the corners from the XML file (I don't know the structure of the XML file)

   My corners:

   ```
   upper left  (162013.302, 138172.271) 
   lower left  (162013.302, 128171.074) 
   upper right (170015.863, 138172.271) 
   lower right (170015.863, 128171.074)
   ```
3. create a [World file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) with a simple script (without gdal or rasterio) with only 2 corners points

   ```
   x1,y1 = [162013.302,  138172.271] # upper left corner
   x2,y2 = [170015.863,  128171.074  # lower right corner
   rasterx  = 7988
   rastery =  9983
   # pixel size 
   #x-component of the pixel width (x scale)
   ppx = (x2-x1)/rasterx
   # y-component of the pixel height (y scale)
   ppy = (y2-y1)/rastery
   print(ppx, ppy)
   (1.0018228592889353, -1.0018227987578898)
   # x-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
   xcenter = x1 + (ppx * .5)
   # y-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
   ycenter = y1 + (ppy * .5)
   print(xcenter,ycenter)
   (162013.80291142964, 138171.77008860064)
   # write the worldfile
   with open('satel.tfw', "w") as worldfile:
       worldfile.write(str(ppx)+"\n")
       worldfile.write(str(0)+"\n") # y-component of the pixel width (y-skew), generaly = 0 
       worldfile.write(str(0)+"\n") # y-component of the pixel width (y-skew), generaly = 0 
       worldfile.write(str(ppy)+"\n")
       worldfile.write(str(xcenter)+"\n")
       worldfile.write(str(ycenter)+"\n")
   ```
4. with gdal and the 4 corners points as ground control points.

   ```
   from osgeo import gdal
   fp= [[0,rasterx,rasterx,0],[0,0,rastery,rastery]]
   tp= [[162013.302, 170015.863, 170015.863, 162013.302], [ 128171.074,128171.074,   138172.271,   138172.271]]
   pix = list(zip(fp[0],fp[1]))
   coor= list(zip(tp[0],tp[1]))
   # compute the gdal.GCP parameters
   gcps = []
   for index, txt in enumerate(pix):
       gcps.append(gdal.GCP())
       gcps[index].GCPPixel = pix[index][0]
       gcps[index].GCPLine = rastery-int(pix[index][1])
       gcps[index].GCPX = coor[index][0]
       gcps[index].GCPY = coor[index][1]
       geotransform = gdal.GCPsToGeoTransform( gcps )
       print(geotransform)
       (162013.302, 1.0018228592889353, 0.0, 138172.271, 0.0, -1.0018227987578898)
       xcenter = geotransform[0] + (geotransform[1] * .5)
       ycenter = geotransform[3] + (geotransform[5] * .5)
       print(xcenter,ycenter)
       (162013.80291142964, 138171.77008860064)
       # write the worldfile
       ...
   ```
5. There are other solutions like [tab2tfw.py](https://github.com/sitn/sitn_python_lib/blob/master/utilities/tab2tfw.py) of Michael Kalbermatten (this is exactly the same problem as MapInfo tab file) or using [affine6p](https://pypi.org/project/affine6p/), [nudged-py](https://github.com/axelpale/nudged-py) or [Affine_Fit](https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/affine-fit/) to estimate the affine transformation parameters between two sets of 2D points but but be careful that raster data, coming from its image processing origins, uses a different referencing system to access pixels (see [Python affine transforms](http://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html))

Example with Numpy  and the 4 corners points (Affine transformation) ( 0,0 origin in the upper left )

```
import numpy as np
fp = np.matrix([[0,rasterx,rasterx,0],[0,0,rastery,rastery]])
newline = [1,1,1,1]
fp  = np.vstack([fp,newline])
tp = np.matrix([[162013.302, 170015.863, 170015.863, 162013.302], [ 128171.074,128171.074,   138172.271,   138172.271]])
M = tp * fp.I
print(M)
matrix([[     1.00182286,      0.        , 162013.302     ],
        [     0.        ,      1.0018228 , 128171.074     ]])
```

Example of result with nugged ( 0,0 origin in the upper left )

```
import nudged
from_pt = [(0, 0), (rasterx, 0), (rasterx, rastery), (0, rastery)]
to_pt = [(162013.302, 128171.074), (170015.863, 128171.074), (170015.863, 138172.271), (162013.302, 138172.271)]
trans = nudged.estimate(from_pt, to_pt)
print(trans.get_matrix())
[[1.0018228223855314,0, 162013.3021473922],        
[0, 1.0018228223855314,   128171.0738820626], 
[0, 0, 1]]
```